# How to block robots without robots.txt

Tags: search-engine, web-crawler, robots.txt

As we know, robots.txt helps us avoid indexing of certain webpages/section by web crawlers/robots. But there are certain disadvantages by using this method: 1. the web crawlers might not listen to robots.txt file; 2. you are exposing the folders you want to protect to everybody;

There is another way of blocking the folders you want to protect from crawlers? Keep in mind that those folders might be wanted to be accessible from the browser (like /admin).

Answer (score 2):

Check the `User-Agent` header on requests and issue a 403 if the header contains the name of a robot. This will block all of the honest robots but not the dishonest ones. But then again, if the robot was really honest, it would obey `robots.txt`.

Comment: i though about making a whitelist with user agents, but is dirty and some new user agents might get banned. some other solution???